Building Milvus on Mac M3: Errors Encountered During Distribution Setup
I am attempting to customize and build Milvus for distributed use on my Apple M3 system with 16GB of RAM. I want to create a custom Milvus image and use milvus-operator to start the system. However, I am uncertain if I need to modify milvus-operator due to its relationship with the official Docker repository.
While following the instructions in milvus/DEVELOPMENT.md, I've encountered issues during the build process. Here are my steps:

Building Milvus with Docker:

./scripts/devcontainer.sh up
docker exec -ti milvus_builder_1 bash
make milvus



This resulted in the following error:
CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: /usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FetchContent.cmake:1662 (message):
  Build step for knowhere failed: 1


Building Milvus on a local OS/shell environment:

./scripts/install_deps.sh
make



This led to another error:
error: unknown type name 'AuthorizationRef'

Could you please assist me in resolving these build issues?

Make sure conan and all the pre-requisites are installed
https://github.com/milvus-io/milvus/discussions/35614
Mac is sometimes picky on some of the build tools.
